# Are there any LVM like solutions for Windows?

Tags: windows, lvm

Are there any LVM like solutions for Windows?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29

Answer (score 10):

They're called "Dynamic disks" in Windows. (Note that the feature is unmaintained and apparently not fast.)

- MSDN: [Basic and Dynamic Disks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363785%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Recent releases (Windows 10 and Server 2016) have "Storage Spaces", which is a more modern replacement.

Answer (score 5):

Things have changed a great deal since this question was asked. Windows does support a form of LVM called *Storage Spaces* now. It has almost identical flexibility and features.

See link below for some good Q & A on the feature.

[windows-10-storage-spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces)

Comment: Storage Spaces has been mentioned in the other question

Comment: what other question?

Comment: my mistake. *Answer*, not *question*

Comment: oh yeah i see it. Someone should mark that the answer...

Answer (score 2):

There is also **Veritas Volume Manager** (VxVM) available for Windows:

- Youtube: [How to create new volume in Veritas Volume Manager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=946WSmdgJoM) (4,430 views • 27 Dec 2012)
- [Managing storage with Veritas Storage Foundation for Windows (I)](https://shabaztech.com/managing-storage-veritas-storage-foundation-windows-part/)
- [1.5.3 Volumes under control of VERITAS Volume Manager (VxVM)](https://software.fujitsu.com/jp/manual/manualfiles/m120010/b1fw5971/02enz201/b5971-00-01-05-07.html)

This manager is even more flexible than LVM:
[image: Figure 1.6 Relationships between volumes, VM disks and physical disks (1)]

---

Also there is [WinBTRFS](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs) port to Windows.

BTRFS supports one (or more) *subvolumes* across several / different devices:

[image: Show the relationship of Btrfs filesystem to hard-drive partitions and mounted directories.]

---

Also there are two active **ZFS** ports to Windows:

- [openzfsonwindows/ZFSin](https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/ZFSin) (the initial prototype)
- [openzfsonwindows/openzfs](https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/openzfs) (the proper port of OpenZFS)

It also supports non-physical volumes and their management:

[image: The fourth level of ZFS consists of datasets and volumes]